# Fix the kernel dropping packet coming from an external network

Tags: linux, networking, libpcap

I have the following configuration:

I have a machine (I'll call it 1) with two interfaces, eth0 which is the external interface and possesses an IP address associated to let's say a network A, and eth1 which doesn't have an IP address and sniff packet in network B using pcap. My problem is that I want to send packets from eth0 to a machine inside network B (let's 2).

To do so I added a route entry in 1 with the interface to get to 2 (eth1), IP and GW of 2.

After I do this, using wireshark I can see UDP packets in 2 but it looks like the kernel is not forwarding the packet to applications. I checked the field, dest mac, port and dest Ip are correct, the source ip and mach are the ones from eth0 which is also correct since eth1 doesn't have an IP. There is no firewall or iptables rules (everything is on default), spoofing check is disabled and in the iptables input I can see the counter being incremented each time one of the packet arrives in 2.

Other info: Both machines are ubuntu 14.02

Comment: can you post the _ip route_ and_ifconfig_ output with the routing rules? also, what is the relation to c language?

Comment: Sorry for the immage quality do you need any other command?: 
https://s31.postimg.org/efw2q3l57/WP_20160706_001.jpg
https://s31.postimg.org/iqaqloq8b/WP_20160706_002.jpg
https://s31.postimg.org/k6m93tt57/WP_20160706_003.jpg
https://s31.postimg.org/p6oapio5n/WP_20160706_004.jpg

Comment: Also, in the wireshark pic you can see the external interface of machine 1 ip *.98 sending to 2 *.103. All the images are obtained from machine *.103

Comment: i dont see the interface eth1 anywhere in the output you uploaded.. correct me if im wrong: eth1 is on machine "1" and connects (though local network) to machine "2", right?

Comment: Yes, eth1 is on the same network than machine 2 (but eth1 doesn't have an IP)

Comment: In wireshark you can see a packet sent by machine 1 arrive to machine two with the source information of eth0 (which is wanted). I don't understand why the packet doesn't go past the nic level. I tried with another node (in the same sub-net as machine 2) generating traffic and everything works fine.

Comment: im sorry, i still dont understand your setup.. can you clarify eth1's role here? on a different angle, perhaps the packets are dropped by the kernel or netfilter? try this - [link](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/). also, can you post the output of _iptables -nvL_?

Comment: eth0 is 1's interface to a different subnet while eth1 is 1's interface to the subnet where 2 is. 1's eth0 is used to sniff packet in the subnet of machine 2. 1's is transparent to 2's (i.e. 2's cannot ping 1's, 1's takes care of intercepting packets and sending them out and in of 2's subnet). Everything works fine if 1's is not the source of the packets but in this case I need to send statistics from 1 to 2.

Comment: https://s32.postimg.org/czgbvmlc5/WP_20160707_001.jpg here's a pic from 2's IP table. The number in input increments every 5 seconds by two (1's exactly sends two packets every 5 seconds to 2). I thought about enabling forwarding too but it didn't help.

Comment: sorry for the delay :) what about 1's iptables? does the output increments as well?

Comment: Don't worry :) Thanks for your support! I'll check as soon as possible (I guess it does since I can see the packet in machine 2)

Comment: Yes the chain gets incremented. I'm now trying to use another udp packet sender application to check that the problem is not in my program.

Comment: It was a feature of our software that was corrupting the communication. Thanks for your support @sagivd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a feature of our software that was corrupting the communication. Generally if there are no un-standard iptables rules or firewall, adding an arp entry is enough to solve this kind of problem.